# How write argument null exception and invalid exception?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, exception, nunit

I am try to write a class for Register CommandHandler

```
public virtual void RegisterCommandHandler<T>(string messageType, Action<T, MetaData> handler)
    {
        _handlers.Add(messageType, (command, metadata) => handler((T)command, metadata));

    }
```

I want to handle two exceptions:

1. handler null exception
2. invalid handler exception

I try to do it following way.but it was not success

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(handler.ToString())) 
       throw new ArgumentNullException("NullException","null value");
```

please help me to write validations 
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking to see if the handler is null directly.

```
if (handler == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("handler cannot be null", "handler");
```

The reason you're having a problem now is that if handler is null, handler.ToString() will throw a NullReferenceException.